Fallo al encontrar el valor de "epsilon" (Anomaly Detection)
Estoy haciendo el tercer curso de la especialización en "Machine Learning" ofrecida por la plataforma "Coursera". Se llama "Unsupervised Learning, Recommenders, Reinforcement Learning". En la prueba final de la semana 1 hay un ejercicio en el que tenemos que implementar una función (select_threshold) para elegir el valor umbral (epsilon) más adecuado que nos permita identificar los datos de entrada como anomalía (y == 1) o no (y == 0). Para esto, usamos parte de los datos de entrenamiento como conjunto de validación. Entonces, como argumentos de entrada en nuestra función tenemos por un lado las etiquetas verdaderas (y_val) asignadas a estos ejemplos de entrenamiento y, por otro lado, la probabilidad de cada uno de estos valores (p_val). Esta probabilidad la calculamos previamente según una distribución gaussiana, la cual queda determinada ya que conocemos la media y la varianza. Estos dos parámetros los obtenemos en la función creada en el primer ejercicio de esta prueba (el ejercicio del que hablo es el 2).
Para elegir el mejor valor para epsilon usamos el concepto "F1 score", el cual se define como sigue:

Por lo que necesitamos de los conceptos "precision" y "recall" para calcular "F1":

, donde "tp" es el número de predicciones positivas verdaderas ("true positives"); "fp", el número de predicciones positivas falsas ("false positives") y; "fn", el número de predicciones negativas falsas ("false negatives").
La parte del algoritmo select_threshold que tenemos que implementar es en la que decidimos si el "epsilon" considerado es mejor de acuerdo a si su "F1" es mayor o menor. Por tanto, tenemos que calcular los "tp", "fp" y "fn" de cada epsilon para obtener los valores para "prec" y "rec" y, así, su "F1 score". Esto es lo que hacemos en el código a continuación con el añadido de que si el algoritmo sólo hace predicciones negativas (tp==fp==0) para evitar la indeterminación que habría al calcular "prec" le asignamos 0. En este caso, lo mismo ocurriría con "F1 score" por lo que también le asignamos 0.
# UNQ_C2
# GRADED FUNCTION: select_threshold

def select_threshold(y_val, p_val): 
    """
    Finds the best threshold to use for selecting outliers 
    based on the results from a validation set (p_val) 
    and the ground truth (y_val)
    
    Args:
        y_val (ndarray): Ground truth on validation set
        p_val (ndarray): Results on validation set
        
    Returns:
        epsilon (float): Threshold chosen 
        F1 (float):      F1 score by choosing epsilon as threshold
    """ 

    best_epsilon = 0
    best_F1 = 0
    F1 = 0
    
    step_size = (max(p_val) - min(p_val)) / 1000
    
    for epsilon in np.arange(min(p_val), max(p_val), step_size):
    
        ### START CODE HERE ### 
        
        # Inicializamos a 0 (en cada iteración) las variables que almacenan el número  
        # de ejemplos "true positives", "false positives" y " false negatives"
        tp = 0
        fp = 0
        fn = 0
         
        for i in range(len(p_val)):
            # Predicción que le corresponde a cada ejemplo
            if p_val[i] < epsilon:
                y_i = 1 
            else:
                y_i = 0
            # Vemos si la predicción es un "tp", un "fp" o un "fn" y contabilizamos
            if y_val[i] == 1 & y_i == 1:
                tp += 1
            if y_val[i] == 0 & y_i == 1:
                fp += 1
            if y_val[i] == 1 & y_i == 0:
                fn += 1
        
        if tp + fp == 0:            # Si el algoritmo solo tiene predicciones negativas asignamos 0 a "precision"
            prec = 0 
        else:                       # Sino, calculamos su valor de forma normal
            prec = tp/(tp + fp)

        rec = tp/(tp + fn)          # Calculamos la métrica de error "recall"

        if prec+rec == 0:           
            F1 = 0                  # Para evitar dividir por cero le asignamos 0 a "F1 score"
        else:
            F1 = 2*prec*rec/(prec+rec)
                
        ### END CODE HERE ### 
        
        if F1 > best_F1:
            best_F1 = F1
            best_epsilon = epsilon
        
    return best_epsilon, best_F1

Sin embargo, al testear el código:
p_val = multivariate_gaussian(X_val, mu, var)
epsilon, F1 = select_threshold(y_val, p_val)

print('Best epsilon found using cross-validation: %e' % epsilon)
print('Best F1 on Cross Validation Set: %f' % F1)
    
# UNIT TEST
select_threshold_test(select_threshold)

Los valores de "epsilon" y "F1 score" no coinciden:
Best epsilon found using cross-validation: 8.981862e-02
Best F1 on Cross Validation Set: 0.900000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d487302cf8bb> in <module>
      6 
      7 # UNIT TEST
----> 8 select_threshold_test(select_threshold)

~/work/public_tests.py in select_threshold_test(target)
      7 
      8     best_epsilon, best_F1 = target(y_val, p_val)
----> 9     assert np.isclose(best_epsilon, 0.04, atol=0.3 / 1000), f"Wrong best_epsilon. Expected: {0.04} got: {best_epsilon}"
     10     assert best_F1 == 1, f"Wrong best_F1. Expected: 1 got: {best_F1}"
     11 

AssertionError: Wrong best_epsilon. Expected: 0.04 got: 0.28014

Expected Output:
Best epsilon found using cross-validation:  8.99e-05
Best F1 on Cross Validation Set:    0.875
Si alguien me puede dar alguna idea para detectar qué puede estar fallando..

No puedo indagar mucho en él código ahora, pero una observación, cuidado con usar el operador & (bitwise-AND) como "sustituto" de and (boolean-AND): 1 == 1 and 0 == 0 => True mientras que
1 == 1 & 0 == 0 => False, en cambio (1 == 1) & (0 == 0) => True, aunque pueda funcionar con bools (0-1), hay que tener presente que los operadores a nivel de bits tiene preferencia con respecto a los operadores de comparación, a diferencia de los operadores boleanos.

¿Te importaría explicarme con un poco más de detalle por qué 1==1 & 0==0=> False?

Hola @Alfonso, básicamente porque al tener  & precedencia sobre  ==, la expresión realmente se evaua como 1 == (1 & 0) == 0, si desarrollamos 1 & 0 es 0 (0b0 & 0b1 = 0b0 = 0), quedando  1 == 0 == 0, eso es una comparación encadenada, que en Python se evalúa como 1 == 0 and 0 == 0 que queda como False and True que es False. Si confirmas que este era la causa del error puedo crear una respuesta detallando la explicaión más y la diferencia de los dos operadores y cuando usarlos, al no disponer de los datos de entrada es complicado reproducir el problema.

Gracias por la explicación! Sí, lo he comprobado y parece que ese era el fallo. Estaría genial que subieras la explicación que dices :)

El principal problema que presenta el código está en las comparaciones, como:
if y_val[i] == 0 & y_i == 1:

El operador &
El operador & es el "bitwise AND" o "AND bit a bit". Es un operador binario que actúa a nivel de bits.
Mejor verlo con un ejemplo, si tenemos los números en binario 0011101011 y 1011000111 y les aplicamos un AND bit a bit (0b0011101011 & 0b1011000111), tenemos:
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
& & & & & & & & & &
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
| | | | | | | | | |
v v v v v v v v v v
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1

como se puede ver solo es cuestion tomar cada bit de un operando y el bit correspondiente (misma posición) del otro operando y aplicarles un AND.
Cuando aplicas el operador & a dos enteros lo haces bit a bit también en sus formas binarias, de hecho, el ejemplo anterior es equivalente a:
>>> 235 & 711
195

Si obtenemos la representación en binario de los operandos y del resultado veremos que coincide con lo anterior:
>>> bin(235)
'0b11101011'
>>> bin(711)
'0b1011000111'
>>> bin(195)
'0b11000011'


Nota: tener en cuenta que los ceros no significativos (a la izquierda) no son representados.

Eso significa que cuando haces True & False realmente la operación es 0b1 & 0b0 que es 0b0, que es 0 en decimal y que equivale a False, que es lo esperado para un "True and False", de hecho el resultado es siempre correcto en este caso para cualquiera de las posibilidades:
>>> True & True
True
>>> True & False
False
>>> False & True
False
>>> False & False
False

Entonces... ¿Cuál es el problema?
El problema (aparte de que realmente no tendriamos que usar este operador aquí, lo veremos después) es que los operadores bit a bit tiene prioridad con respecto a los operadores de comparación en el orden de evaluación, tal como ocurre con la multiplicación con respecto a la suma.
Si tenemos la expresión:
y_val[i] == 1 & y_i == 0

y le damos a y_val[i] un valor de 1 y a y_i uno de 0 tendremos:
1 == 1 & 0 == 0

podriamos esperar que eso de True:
1 == 1  &  0 == 0
|____|     |____|
   |         |
 True   &   True => True

El problema es que por el orden de evaluación comentado, en realidad lo que pasa es:
1 == 1 & 0 == 0
     |___|
       |
1 ==   0  == 0

La expresión 1 == 0 == 0 es lo que se conoce como una comparación encadenada, en Python eso es azúcar sintáctico para expresar realmente:
1 == 0 and 0 == 0

que se evalúa como (*No del todo cierto, ver short-circuit más abajo):
1 == 0 and 0 == 0
|____|     |____|
   |         |
False  and  True => False 

El operador and, el AND lógico.
Arriba aparece otro operador, and, que es el AND lógico o AND "boleano", el operador que realmente deberiamos estar usando en nuestro caso ya que estamos realizando una operación lógica en las que ambos operandos son bools (dos expresiones de comparación cuya evaluación resultan en bools).
¿Qué operador uso entonces?
En general:

Para operaciones lógicas usa los operadores (lógicos) and or y not.

Para operar bit a bit usa los operadores & (AND),   | (OR), ~ (NOT), ^ (XOR), << (desplazamiento a la izquierda)    y >> (desplazamiento a la derecha). Se aplican sobre enteros, en la representación que sea.


En el caso que nos ocupa, podrias hacer:
if (y_val[i] == 0) & (y_i == 1):

y funcionaría, pero por lo general no merece la pena y para evitar efectos colaterales como el que causa nuestro error mejor hacer:
if y_val[i] == 0 and y_i == 1:

Evaluación de cortocircuito
Otra diferencia notable entre and y & es que and implementa una evaluación mínima (short-circuit). Si el primer operando, la expresión a su izquierda, se evalúa como False, lo que hay a la derecha no se ejecuta siquiera y el and resulta en False. Por ejemplo en:
if sum(array1) == 0 and sum(arr2) == 0:

si sum(array1) es 0, sum(arr2) no se ejecuta siquiera.
Los operadores a nivel de bits no pueden lógicamente implementar esto, if (sum(array1) == 0) & (sum(arr2) == 0): aunque funcione es considerablemente menos eficiente porque sum(arr2) se ejecuta siempre. Lo mismo se aplica a | vs or.
La sobrecarga de operadores
Notese que dependiendo del tipo de los operandos los operadores pueden tener una función u otra, de hecho los operadores &, |, ^, << y >> pueden sobrecargarse implementando sus respectivos métodos "mágicos". En nuestro caso los operandos son siempre enteros o bools (subtipo de int realmente), pero, por ejemplo:

En el caso de los conjuntos de Python (set), | es el operador para la unión de conjuntos, & para la intersección y ^ el de la diferencia simétrica.

Los arrays de Numpy también tienen sobrecargados estos operadores, por ejemplo & aplica un and lógico sobre dos arrays de bools de forma vectorizada (numpy.logical_and).



En definitiva, tus condicionales deberían quedar como:
if y_val[i] == 1 and y_i == 1:
    tp += 1
elif y_val[i] == 0 and y_i == 1:
    fp += 1
elif y_val[i] == 1 and y_i == 0:
    fn += 1

En principio, dado que la entrada son arrays de NumPy, podrias hacer uso del mismo y vectorizar las operaciones, algo así:
y_i_t = p_val < epsilon
y_val_t = y_val == 1 

tp = (y_val_t & y_i_t).sum()
fp = (~y_val_t & y_i_t).sum()
fn = (y_val_t & ~y_i_t).sum()

prec = 0 if (p := tp + fp) == 0 else tp / p 
rec = tp / (tp + fn)
F1 = 0 if (p := prec + rec) == 0 else 2 * prec * rec  / p 

